# ReactJS using jquery for animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to render a component, but the value is inside a jQuery function that checks for changes in an input field.

The console returns this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDocument]).
>   If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead 
>   or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React
>   add-ons.  Check the render method of `Result`

the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Result from './Result';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import ReactFM from '../lib/ReactFM';
import { config } from '../config';

export let reactfm = new ReactFM(config.apiKey);

let name = $(() => {
  $('.input-search').keypress(() => {
    let inp = $('.input-search').val();
    return reactfm.searchArtists(inp);
  });
});

class SearchResults extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-results">
        <Result avatar="" name={name} desc="um deus" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: What does `return reactfm.searchArtists(inp)` return?

Comment: the name fetched from lastfm api

Comment: Please add your Result component to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no good reason to use jQuery when you are using React.

If you are (and you should be) writing the html that contains the input element in JSX as a higher level React component, you can reference the input either by a ref attribute or add a keydown event listener to the input itself.

Example:

```
const HigherLevelParentComponent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultState() {
    searchQuery: ''
  },

  searchArtists(event) {
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: event.target.value
    })
  },

  render() {
    (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onKeyDown={(event) => this.searchArtists(event)}/>
        <Result ... /> // You probably want this to be a mapped array of Result components with unique props instead
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

You will also want to include a function that searches through the searchable data and returns an array of objects that you could then render into Result components using mapping and props. How you do this will depend on where the searchable data is coming from (React store, database table on the back-end, etc.).

Also, you mentioned using jQuery for animations but did not elaborate.